# Create a new status bar

Tags: ios, statusbar

I'm creating prototype apps and need to have a custom carrier instead of showing AT&T/Verizon or whatever actual carrier is on the phone.

I have a fake home screen which the app launches from, but want to have the custom status bar appear for it and the screens after. These are all black statusbars.

Any suggestions for the best way to do this? I created a UIViewController subclass that simply adds an image of the status bar with a label set to the current time, but this won't work if I use a nav bar.

Ideally this is done in a way where I can use the real status bar, but I can put a uiview over the carrier area with the text I'd like. This way I don't have to code in a time and battery icon.

Note that since these are prototypes, I don't need to worry about app store approval.

Comment: If your customers are incapable of focusing on your app instead of the status bar, why not just hide the status bar? Let your app be full screen.

Comment: Add a UIView directly onto the main-window that mimics a status-bar - make sure you add it after the rootViewController has been set (towards your navigationController). You may have to resize your rootViewController to leave room for the fake-status-bar.

Comment: @rmaddy We need the status bar because when the app is actually released it will have a status bar. Also if you hide the status bar on the home screen, it's obvious the home screen is fake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few different ways, I stumbled upon this code that works: https://gist.github.com/guidosabatini/4066796

Haven't been able to test on a live device.

This is what I was using previously (with some modifications): http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2010/11/custom-status-bar-ios/

Answer (score 1):

hide the real status bar and make one with UIView or make a image that looks like it in a UIImageView